# is concurrent delivery possible when using sender_dependent_default_transport_maps in Postfix?

Tags: postfix-mta

In order to send only certain emails through "certified mailboxes" (the italian PEC system, a form of "registred mail") we use this setup:

main.cf

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_relay
```

sender_relay

```
@first.tld relay-smtps:smtps.our-provider.tld:465
@second.tld relay-smtps:smtps.our-provider.tld:465
```

sasl_passwd

```
one.mailbox@first.tld one.mailbox@first.tld:PASSWORD
another.mailbox@second.tld another.mailbox@second.tld:PASSWORD
```

This works pretty well, as long as you only send emails to a single recipient.

As soon as we send them to different recipients though, our counterpart complains that the addresses specified in To and Cc do not match the ones that should actually be there (forward path).

What this means is best explained by the last 4 lines of this piece of mail.log:

```
May 13 16:43:15 ourhostname postfix/qmgr[21826]: 153821434F6: removed
May 13 16:43:18 ourhostname postfix/smtpd[28249]: connect from internal.server.tld[10.20.30.40]
May 13 16:43:18 ourhostname postfix/smtpd[28249]: 81B971434F6: client=internal.server.tld[10.20.30.40]
May 13 16:43:18 ourhostname postfix/cleanup[28252]: 81B971434F6: message-id=<033cb34227a3482d8258d919bf3863bd@internal.server.tld>
May 13 16:43:18 ourhostname postfix/qmgr[21826]: 81B971434F6: from=<one.mailbox@first.tld>, size=2549002, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 13 16:43:18 ourhostname postfix/smtpd[28249]: 8D064143527: client=internal.server.tld[10.20.30.40]
May 13 16:43:18 ourhostname postfix/cleanup[28252]: 8D064143527: message-id=<033cb34227a3482d8258d919bf3863bd@internal.server.tld>
May 13 16:43:18 ourhostname postfix/qmgr[21826]: 8D064143527: from=<one.mailbox@first.tld>, size=2548877, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 13 16:43:18 ourhostname postfix/smtpd[28249]: disconnect from internal.server.tld[10.20.30.40] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=2 rcpt=2 data=2 quit=1 commands=10

May 13 16:43:20 ourhostname postfix/relay-smtps/smtp[28635]: 8D064143527: to=<recipient.one@legalmail.it>, relay=smtps.our-provider.tld[1.1.1.1]:465, delay=1.7, delays=0.05/0.01/0.56/1.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 49McqH4wCMz2LfNLM)
May 13 16:43:20 ourhostname postfix/qmgr[21826]: 8D064143527: removed
May 13 16:43:20 ourhostname postfix/relay-smtps/smtp[28634]: 81B971434F6: to=<recipient.two@pec.it>, relay=smtps.our-provider.tld[1.1.1.1]:465, delay=1.8, delays=0.05/0.01/0.62/1.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 49McqH4y1Rz2MKHTD)
May 13 16:43:20 ourhostname postfix/qmgr[21826]: 81B971434F6: removed
```

As you can see, the message is being split and delivery is tried for each piece (two recipients - two deliveries).

Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

My bad... I overlooked that Postfix has been receiving the message already split into two by the internal mail server: `disconnect from internal.server.tld[10.20.30.40] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=2 rcpt=2 data=2 quit=1 commands=10`.